# How to Pass dataItem to a js function on a KendoGrid cell custom click

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a KendoGrid that have a column like:

```
{
      title: "Column1",
      template: <a href="javascript:customJsFunction(#= data #)">click here</a>',
},
```

..first this code doesnt work.
Im trying to pass the whole "data" (the data for the current row) to a javascript function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this template using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
"<a href='javascript:customJsFunction(#= JSON.stringify(data) #)'>Click here</a>"
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ItISeS)